# Neo plugin -> Craft CMS Core ... is this idea still alive?

Tags: craft-features, plugin-neo

With a look on https://craftcms.com/roadmap: I remember, there was a ticket to build a Neo alternative into the core of Craft CMS v5 (and a migration tool for existing projects with Neo).

Unfortunately I can't remember the ticket ID or naming ... but it seems to have disappeared?

I'm asking this only for information and curiosity ... I am aware this is a huge workload to do.

Does anyone have more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This answer contains information about future Craft releases. Please see the [official roadmap](https://craftcms.com/roadmap) for updates.

---

We don't have plans to precisely replicate Neo's functionality, but many users associate this functionality with Craft 5’s new "nested elements" architecture. This dramatically increases the Matrix field's capabilities via support for reusable global fields, infinite recursive nesting, and block types defined as entry types.

On the roadmap, this spans multiple issues:

- Nested Matrix fields [#9783](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/9783)
- Globalize entry types [#10663](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/10663)
- Content storage refactor [#12954](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/12954)
- Field instances [#8497](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8497)

View the [5.0 branch](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/5.0) on GitHub for more information!

Comment: Fun fact: [#12954](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/12954) was started by myself ... didn't expected this :)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of "Inception fields", a new field type that was planned for Craft 5. That idea has been scrapped; instead Craft 5.0 will introduce new features for the native Matrix field that should cover most, if not all, use cases for Neo and SuperTable – including:

- Nested Matrix fields
- Global Matrix sub fields
- Field instances (possible to use the same field multiple times within the same field layout)
- Matrix view modes

I'm not aware if Craft 5 will include a Neo/SuperTable to Matrix migration in core, but given the popularity of these plugins, I'm fairly confident that a migration will be available (in one way or another).

Craft 5.0 is currently in alpha, with a beta release expected in early 2024 and GA some time after that.

Comment: Ah, "Inception field" is probably the term Marc was looking for!

Comment: Yes ... "Inception field" was the keyword I was looking for. And yes, these missing features of the Matrix field were the reason for me to choose Neo. I'm very happy with Neo, but I'm aware of the overhead of Neo, f.e. additional tables. And yes, these new features of Matrix will resolve my requirements and there will be no need for Neo anymore. But with the new Matrix in Craft 5 I'm really worried about the support of Neo in future. And with a look for my existing projects and templates for new projects: I'm using Neo excessively ... the migration to Matrix will be ​really hard.

Comment: @Marc AFAIK the Neo vendor is still planning to keep supporting it for Craft 5. Look in the issues in Neo's Github repo for relevant issues/discussions.